# SchemaExport vs HiLo algorithm

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm using schemaExport to create an in-memory database for my automatic tests. I have several (5) classes mapping their HiLo identity to the same database table, using one column per class.

This gives me a table, hibernate_unique_key, w. 5 columns. When generating the database using scemaexport, however, the table only gets a single column (IPoolActivation), thereby making my querys fail, since the mappings in the model are now invalid. I've tried manually querying the in memory database to create the table, but I would rather know how to make schemaexport do it right.

A snippet from one of my mapping files;

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int32">
  <generator class="hilo">
    <param name="column">IENPool</param>
  </generator>
</id>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a bug (or it is by design) in SchemaExport, and it only looks at the hibernate_unique_key table once when it sees the first entity with HiLo.  As a result all HiLo entities must use the same column.

However, I recently needed a custom IdGenerator which I based off the same base class in NHibernate that HiLo inherits from.  For this database I needed one column per table (it was for a legacy database that was setup with a HiLo style generator that way).

You can see what I did here if it helps:

[Implementing a custom id Generator for nHibernate](http://lucisferre.net/2009/07/14/implementing-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate/)

[Generate custom DDL for a custom id Generator](http://www.lucisferre.net/2009/08/15/Generate-Custom-DDL-for-your-Custom-Id-Generator-with-nHibernate)

[Entire post on nhibernate.info](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/creating-a-custom-id-generator-for-nhibernate)

Comment: Thanks! For now i'll go with the single column solution, but i really appreciate the example.

Comment: Yeah I definitely recommend that to keep it simple.  I only did this because of the legacy requirement.

Comment: It turns out that this is by design and still causes issues for developers (including myself). Look here: https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2687